# Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be Linear Transformation and $f(t)$ be any Polynomial, then $\ker f(T)$ is invariant under T.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be Linear Transformation and $f(t)$ be any
>   Polynomial, then $\ker f(T)$  is invariant under T.

I tried to prove. I am stuck with the last step.

Let $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$

$x\in \ker f(T)$

$\implies f(T)(x)=0$

We need to prove that $T(x)\in \ker f(T)$

$f(T)(T(x))=a_{0}T(x)+a_{1}T(T(x))+\cdots+a_{n}T^{n}(T(x))$

$...$

How to prove that this quantity is zero?

Comment: Use the fact that $x\in\text{Ker}f(T)$

Comment: $x\in\text{Ker}f(T)\implies a_{0}x+a_{1}T(x)+\cdots+a_{n}T^{n}(x)=0$, then apply $T$ to both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quantity is$$T\bigl(a_0x+a_1T(x)+\cdots+a_nT^n(x)\bigr)=T(0)=0.$$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi At no point I wrote that $a_0x=0$. Aren't you assuming that $x\in\ker f(T)$? Doesn't that mean that$$a_0x+a_1T(x)+\cdots+a_nT^n(x)=0?$$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No, it doesn't. In general$$\ker(f)=\{x\in V\,|\,f(x)=0\}.$$

Comment: My bad, I misread and thought it was $\ker T$.